# Safe primes and subgroups

Tags: diffie-hellman, group-theory, safe-prime

I've been reading about safe primes and their use in: [Cryptography Engineering](http://ttps://www.schneier.com/books/cryptography_engineering/) by Niels Ferguson, Bruce Schneier, and Tadayoshi Kohno.

Having a safe prime $q$ with $q=2p+1$ where $p$ is a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safe_and_Sophie_Germain_primes)

They claim that the elements of the subgroup $p$ are the elements that are preferred to be used. Why?

Why not the elements in $2p$?

Comment: Yes, I consider to use them in Diffie-Hellman.
What is so bad about large group orders?

Comment: No, not really. But the answer given by Occams_Trimmer does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Decisional Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decisional_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_assumption) assumption, on which the key-exchange would be based on does *not* hold in $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$. The reason is that the [Jacobi symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol) "leaks" information about the shared key. Therefore one, instead, works with the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_q^*$ of order $p$, which is intuitively obtained by "quotienting out" this information. (This group is sometimes called the [Schnorr group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_group).) You can read the details on why DDH doesn't hold [here](https://danielslamanig.info/lectures/ModernCrypto18Homework10_solutions.pdf) (Exercise 2).

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for